# Making a collage of several videos

Tags: mixing

I am trying to make a video showing me playing various instruments arranged together in a song. The effect that I want to achieve is exactly like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxlMO5XiSlc).

The person in the video is a friend of mine, and he told me he created the video using iMovie. **But** he was only able to mix two videos at once, so he resorted to mixing two videos, exporting, mixing together with another one and so on.

I already have the various snippets filmed, and I would like to put them together in a collage, but using a software that allows superimposing many videos at once ( at certain points I have eight). What kind of software allows this?

Ideally I would use a Mac, but Linux is also fine (as long as it does not need enormous amounts of resources, since it is an older machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackmagic Design’s DaVinci Resolve offers a free version, is available on Mac, Linux, and Windows, and is well-suited to creating video collages. One of the effects added in version 17 is actually called “video collage” and greatly simplifies the process over past versions.  Additionally, if you synchronize the timecode of all cameras before you start shooting a multi-camera event, it offers features like “live overwrite” and “sync bins” which simplify typical multicam edits.

Adobe Premiere is a viable alternative, but does not run on Linux, and is not free.

Final Cut Pro X is a Mac-only alternative, and also does not offer a free version.

Avid Media Composer is the other big-name player in the NLE space.

Comment: Thank you, DaVinci resolve seems exactly the tool I was looking for!